# When executing assembler code, the error "this interrupt is not defined yet" occurs

Tags: assembly, input, interrupt, emu8086

When I run the written code, the error "this interrupt is not defined yet, it is availabe for custom functions. you can define this interrupt by modifying interrupt vector table refer to the list of supported interrupts and global memory table" occurs when initializing the array

This code was run in emu8086:

```
.model tiny 
.code
ORG 100h
begin: 
JMP start
 
start:
   MOV   AH,9          ; output message0
   MOV   DX, offset mess0                                           
   INT   21h
 
   MOV   DI, offset buff       ; we will write STOSB in DI      
   MOV   BX,4          ; line counter
   MOV   DX,4          ; number counter in line
create:         ;<=====; start input and save ================//
   MOV   CX,2          ; limit the number to 2 characters
   DEC   DX            ; decrement the number counter
@1:
   MOV   AH,1          ; input
   INT   21h
   STOSB               ; store the first character in DI
   LOOP  @1            ; ..followed by the second.
   MOV   AL,' '        ; space/separator
   INT   29h
   STOSB               ; its too in DI..
   OR    DX,DX         ; is it the last number in the line?
   JNZ   create        ; no - fill in the line further
   MOV   AH,9          ; line ended.
   MOV   DX,offset crlf       ; new line!                     
   INT   21h
   DEC   BX            ; decrement the line count
   OR    BX,BX         ; is it last line?
   JZ    next          ; yes - exit the input loop
   MOV   DX,4          ; restore the number of numbers in a string
   JMP   create        ; fill in the next line of the array
 
next:           ;<=====; display the result on the screen ================//
   MOV   AH,9         
   MOV   DX, offset mess1                                                
   INT   21h
 
   MOV   CX,4          ; how many pairs of digits to output
   MOV   SI, offset buff       ; source - buffer                        
print:
   LODSB               ; read the first character
   INT   29h           ; display it on the screen
   LODSB               ; second character..
   INT   29h
   LODSB               ; take a space
   INT   29h
   ADD   SI,12         ; move the pointer to 4 triads of characters
   LOOP  print         ; loop until CX > 0
 
exit:                  ; exit
   XOR   AX,AX
   INT   16h
   INT   20h
 
ret 
 
mess0  DB  'CREATE ARRAY...',13,10
       DB  '====================',13,10,'$'
mess1  DB  '====================',13,10
       DB  'RESULT: $'
crlf   DB  13,10,'$'
buff   DB  80 DUP(0)   
end begin
```

[image]
There is a page of problem

Comment: What is int 29 supposed to do?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  For example, find out what line of code is running when it gives that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use an interrupt that is not implemented by the emulator:

http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-4124.htm

You may need to extend the emulator with support for `int 29h` or ask the emulator developers for help in extending it. Alternatively you can change the calls to `int 29h` to `int 21h`, service 02:

http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm

E.g.

```
    mov dl,'A'    ; write 'A' to std out
    mov ah,02h    ; WRITE CHARACTER TO STANDARD OUTPUT
    int 21h
```

Comment: Or just use the better supported [INT 10/AH=0Eh](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm) which is what the int 29 handler likely calls anyway.

Comment: emu8086 is closed source shareware(?) and AFAIK not really or at all maintained.  If you want a more complete emulation of an 8086 PC, use Bochs to emulate the CPU and hardware, with the open-source BIOS it comes with (e.g. SeaBIOS), and FreeDOS.   And for software development inside it, NASM and a separate debugger or something, unlike emu8086's all-in-one IDE with editor/assembler/debugger.   (DOSBox is also a good option, good enough for most software from that era, but again you're running actual DOS and need an editor, assembler, and debugger.)

Comment: Thanks <3 I just change 29h to 10h/AH=9Eh. Its realy works. I owe you))

Comment: Bear in mind that you're mixing stdout output (`int 21h/AH=0x9`) with BIOS output (`int 10h`). This inconsistency will manifest when you redirect the output of your program into a file or a pipe.